# How to correctly install NumPy in Docker container running on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, pandas, docker, numpy, raspberry-pi

I am trying to host a simple Dash app on a Raspberry Pi in a Docker environment. The app runs as expected locally, but when building for ARMv6 and pulling the image, I get the following error (shortened for brevity):

```
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 
[...]
Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

I build the app for ARMv6 and push it to my DockerHub repository using the following command:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v6 -t <username>/<repo-name>:<tag> --push .
```

The image is then downloaded using `docker-compose pull` into the Docker environment on the Raspbery Pi and started using `docker-compose up`

My Dockerfile contains the following:

```sh
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

# Problems with brotli from piwheels means it needs to be downloaded from another repo.
RUN pip3 install --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && pip3 uninstall -y brotli \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir brotli

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```

Requirements.txt:

```
numpy==1.21.4
pandas==1.3.5
dash==2.0.0
dash-core-components==2.0.0
dash-html-components==2.0.0
dash-bootstrap-components==1.0.2
dash-table==5.0.0
plotly==5.3.1
mysql-connector-python==8.0.27
dash-bootstrap-templates==1.0.4
```

Comment: I see you don't use python-alpine, but maybe the fix given [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68752830/numpy-from-alpine-package-repo-fails-to-import-c-extensions) can work in your case too!

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not change anything for me.